# ActionBar not scrolling to selected tab if this one is outside the visible bounds of actionBar on screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I set up an actionbar in my application. I get back the ActionBar by calling the [Activity.getActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29). Then I set all the Tabs I need thanks to [ActionBar.addTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#addTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab,%20boolean%29) and [ActionBar.newTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab%28%29) methods.

When I am in landscape mode, all my categories are displayed on screen (i.e., user can see all available Tab). I select the last category (on the right of the screen).
After a screen rotation (I'm now in Portrait mode), I save the selected category and restore it on my ActionBar thanks to [ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29) method.

Although the Tab is well selected in the ActionBar (i.e., its label is underlined/highlighted), the considered Tab is not currently visible on screen. Indeed, the screen width is to small to display all available Tabs of ActionBar.

My problem is, `setSelectedNavigationItem` doesn't make the ActionBar scroll to the selected Tab so that the user can see its label. The user must manually scroll into ActionBar to visualize which Tab is currently selected.

Could someone help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Hm - thanks to your question, I found out how to do this - however it's scrolling towards the proper tab at the end automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vadi said in comment: `tab.select();` will automatically scroll to the selected tab. My guess is that you pass the savedinstancestate to super and also set the selected. This would most likely cause the glitch.